# Run Pyinstaller EXE file with elevated priviledges

Tags: python, subprocess, pyqt5, pyinstaller, elevated-privileges

I am writing a pyqt application which requires some subprocess commands to run as admin in all machines. I would prefer to start my script with elevated priviledges. I have checked every possible answer in stackoverflow and i havent found a solution yet. When i run the isAdmin() code that everyone proposes,i get a spam of infinite cmd.exes and nothing else happens. Can anyone give a solution?